# A background with two responsive triangles

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="text-beside-wrapper">
  <div class="text-beside">
      some text goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
  
}
.text-beside-wrapper {
    background-color: #e3dfdc;
    height: 415px;
    width: 300px;
}

.text-beside-wrapper:after {
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;
    border-top: 415px solid #dbd5c5;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

This is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zby230f9/7/

The problem is that it is not responsive. I hope to have the same design, and the two triangles maintain the cutting line connecting two opposite corners no matter what the height and width of the area. Is this doable with CSS?

### Update

I forgot to mention that `height: 415px` and `width: 300px` are used above because that is how the text on desktop makes it that way. I don't want to maintain the same ratio because the height and width of the text area (class `text-beside`) could change with any ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using linear gradients 
https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/54s72wxq/

```
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px), black 50%, transparent 50%) ;
```

Comment: Seems working on Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.  Didn't get a chance to test in Safari. But this is really simple. You dont have to specify the size of the containing rectangle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this css. `vh` is view height and `vw` is view width, so 100% responsive :)
Careful if you use % as mentioned in another answer the height of the parent container needs to be defined.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text-beside-wrapper {
  background-color: #e3dfdc;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 30vw;
}

.text-beside-wrapper:after {
  border-right: 30vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 40vh solid #dbd5c5;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-beside-wrapper">
  <div class="text-beside">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vh and vw are relative to the viewport.

Comment: Thodoris, thanks so much for helping me. I updated the post.

Comment: @curious1 No problem :)  I am not sure though that I get what you mean in your update. Is my answer solving your problem, or you want the sizes of the triangles to be responding to the text inside of them?

Comment: Thodoris, I upvoted your answer. I would like to wait a few days to see if there are other answers that 100% addresses my need. I will work on top of your answer to see if I can make it work. If yes, I will select your answer as the solution. Again, thanks!

Comment: @Thodoris, RenzoCC's answer is what I needed. Really simple and 100% responsive regardless of the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, not tested though:
You can use an SVG file as background with `background-size: 100% 100%;` , it should work.

Or a `background-size: cover;` if you want your background to keep it ratio (but may be cut if the block have a crammed ratio than the svg).